# How to apply a class according to the route in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to switch the `Class` accordingly to the `route`, but it works for the 2 of them but the first one keep the `Class` `active`.

App.vue

```
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link tag="a" class="nav-link" to="/" active-class="active">
            Home
          </router-link>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link tag="a" class="nav-link" to="about" active-class="active">
            About
          </router-link>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link tag="a" class="nav-link" to="form" active-class="active">
            Form
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exact-active-class` instead of `active-class` in your router-link elements.